# How to use the USRP_UHD device in redhawk?

Tags: redhawksdr, usrp

I've installed the UHD device successfully on REDHAWK 1.9. I've tried adjusting the frontend tuner allocation property of the device, but when I try to run it, there is no activity showing up when I monitor the ports.

I don't even know if the redhawk device works properly because when I specify a random IP address, the device can still run normally.

So my question is: How can I use the USRP_UHD device in REDHAWK 1.9.0 to collect and demodulate a signal with a USRP N210?

I know the USRP is working because I am able to create and execute a simple demodulator in GNURadio, but I cannot replicate this in REDHAWK 1.9.

I'm able to start the component without errors, but nothing shows up when I monitor the ports.

Answer (score 0):

You must first launch a Domain, create and launch a Node that contains a USRP_UHD Device, and configure the USRP_UHD Device with the IP address of the target USRP. Then, you must create and launch a Waveform with components that do the signal processing required (i.e. demodulation) and a *usesdevice* relationship that contains an allocation of the USRP_UHD Device.

Using Redhawk 1.9, I tested the behavior of the USRP_UHD Device with bad IP addresses to see if I could reproduce what you described. When I launched a Node containing a USRP_UHD configured with an invalid IP address, the following was reported:

```
ERROR:USRP_UHD_i - USRP COULD NOT BE INITIALIZED!
WARN:USRP_UHD_i - CAUGHT EXCEPTION WHEN INITIALIZING USRP. WAITING 1 SECOND AND TRYING AGAIN
ERROR:USRP_UHD_i - USRP COULD NOT BE INITIALIZED!
ERROR:USRP_UHD_i - Unable to initialize USRP!
```

I then configured the IP address with the correct value and the USRP_UHD initialized properly. Lastly, I configured an invalid IP address using the IDE, and the following error was reported in addition to the error above being printed again:

```
Failed to set property 'USRP_ip_address', due to Invalid Configuration. Unable to initialize USRP based on these properties
IDL:CF/PropertySet/InvalidConfiguration:1.0
```

Since you are not seeing this, there must be a problem with your setup. Describe your setup and the steps you take to launch the Redhawk USRP_UHD device, how you are “adjusting the frontend tuner allocation property”, and what do you mean when you say the Device “can still run normally”. It’s unclear if you are attempting to allocate properly -- are you doing this using a *usesdevice* relationship in the waveform SAD file, as is described on other SO posts?

Comment: I upgraded to Redhawk 1.10. The USRP device is now prebuilt into it. I launched a node with the USRP device and Redhawk was able to find the USRP N210 after I specified the ip address property. Can you please specify on how to use the USRP device in a waveform? I cannot use the USRP device in a waveform, but I can use components to demodulate a pseudosignal.